# Application text and gui size is small

Tags: windows, display-settings, high-dpi

I have still not found how to fix this.

I tried 2 things to solve this :

- Changing the properties of the Application.
- Changing the Display setting costume scale.

[image]

But it just makes others are big but the app is not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://superuser.com/help/editing)

Comment: New posters are not allowed to embed inline images, even though that makes the question easier to read. So other users with that privilege will often embed those images, which can make a question more likely to be answered.

Comment: Ok, but can you guys answer and just I'm pretty triggered when people edit and commenting of out of the topic in my questions.

Comment: But thx for the comment.